# Best way to avoid reloading from cache repititively?

Tags: php, laravel, loops, oop, caching

Consider having a Class whose method is being called in **iteration** n times, and the method in itself has a statement that pulls **data** from a **cache** system - Redis.

Now if this method is called *n* times the cache is also hit *n* times, leading to a continuous **fetch** and **unserializing** of the same data *n times*, which in the case of an interpreter like **PHP** consumes a good amount of time & CPU.

Passing the cached data to this method could also be a no, as we might instantiate n number of instances of this class.

Hence is there a way where we can avoid hitting the cache multiple times in the context of a Class and/or Object?

> Maybe we can somehow use `static` properties of the Object to hold the value?

Comment: It's not clear what your code actually does but it sounds like you'd actually gain in performance if you moved your data into a database and made them into models so you can do a single db query for all the data you need in one go. Alternatively you can cache all the data you need as a single collection in the cache and then discard what you don't need from the cache (though this will take a lot more memory)

Comment: Unit-testing tip; pretend `static` keyword does not even exist, and use it only in situations where you store a service-class's instance-reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, write a service class that:

- Provides getter, which:

  - Loads required value from cache (based on unique-key),
  - But also backups the loaded-value,
  - Finally, returns backupped-value instead of re-loading from cache.
- Provides setter which updates both backup and cache.

Then simply use Laravel's feature to inject and/or get instance of said service-class.

### Example

```php
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

class MyCacheService
{
    protected $backupMap = [];

    /**
     * Requests an instance of this-class from Laravel. 
     *
     * @return MyCacheService|null
     */
    public static function instance()
    {
        return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::make(MyCacheService::class);
    }

    public function get($key)
    {
        $backup = & $this->backupMap[$key];
        if ( ! isset($backup)) {
            $backup = $this->rawGet($key);
        }
        return $buckup;
    }

    public function set($key, $value)
    {
        $this->rawSet($key, $value);
        $this->backupMap[$key] = $value;
    }

    /** Loads from cache */
    private function rawGet($key)
    {
        // ... your normal loading from cache logic goes here,
        // but as sub-example:

        return Cache::get($key);
    }

    /** Saves into cache */
    private function rawSet($key, $value)
    {
        // ... your normal saving into cache logic goes here,
        // but as sub-example:
        Cache::set($key, $value);
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

```
use App\Services\MyCacheService;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

// ...

// Get instance once, like:
$cache = MyCacheService::instance();

// Or like:
/** @var MyCacheService|null $cache */
$cache = App::make(MyCacheService::class);

// Finally, reuse as many times as required, like:
$myValue = $cache->get('my-unique-key');

$myOtherValue = $cache->get('my-other-key');
```

> **Note** that Laravel stores the class's instance for us, else one could use `private static` property named `$instance`, and `return` that from `instance()` method.
>
> **WARNING:** as you may already know, maybe replace rawGet and rawSet's logic.
>
> Also, place `MyCacheService.php` file (which's source is above) in `app/Services` folder.

Comment: Hmmm, Nice I like how sophisticated this solution is but I am wondering if there is harm in just using static property as a cache as the data is not huge, what are your thoughts on that ?

Comment: @BlackBurn027 You may in future need to add unit-tests to the project (if not already), and `static` things are hard to test, because you would need to manually set/unset `static` variables that may affect the behavior (in `setUp` and/or `tearDown` section of the test-class).

Comment: @BlackBurn027 Nevertheless, even above is just a "static property", but said property is managed by `Laravel` for us automatically. **See edit:** `MyCacheService::instance()` should make usage even simpler.

Comment: Makes sense about testability! Thank you, accepting this as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the opinion that you should not use a service-class (which the other answer explains),
then consider using PHP's `$GLOBALS` variable to backup the loaded-Cache (instead of adding yet another custom `static` variable).

### Examples

#### Maybe backup once for all:

In Laravel's `AppServiceProvider.php` file, do something like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

// ...

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    // ...

    public function boot()
    {
        $keyList = [
            'my-unique-key',
            'my-other-key',
        ];

        foreach($keyList as $key) {
            $GLOBALS['cache-' . $key] = Cache::get($key);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, use `$GLOBALS['cache-my-unique-key']` anywhere required.

#### Or, backup per class:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

class YourClass {
    private $myData;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $key = 'my-unique-key';

        $value = & $GLOBALS['cache-' . $key];
        if ( ! isset($value)) {
            $value = Cache::get($key);
        }

        $this->myData = $value;
    }

    // Finally, use `$this->myData` anywhere in this same class.
}
```

> **Note** that as you may already know, in both cases we use `'cache-'` prefix to not overwrite anything by mistake.

Answer (score -1):

You can use static properties to store the cached data and use access it same.

```
class CacheClass
{
    private static $cachedData;

    public function retrieveData()
    {
        if (!isset(self::$cachedData)) {
            // re-assign the value
            self::$cachedData = fetchDataFromCache();
        }
        
        return self::$cachedData;
    }
}
```